# How to click on like/dislike button of YouTube video using selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, selenium, web, webdriver

[image]my code :

```
react_on_video = (input("React: ")).upper()
video_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blablabla"

(After login with my gmail account)

driver.get(video_link)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300);")
time.sleep(1)
if react_on_video == "LIKE":
    Like_button_Full_xpath = "/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch- 
          flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info- 
          renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytd-menu-renderer/div[1]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a/yt- 
          icon-button/button/yt-icon"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(Like_button_Full_xpath).click()
    
if react_on_video == "DISLIKE":
    Dislike_button_Full_xpath = "/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch- 
          flexy/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/ytd-video-primary-info- 
          renderer/div/div/div[3]/div/ytd-menu-renderer/div[1]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[2]/a/yt- 
          icon-button/button/yt-icon"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(Dislike_button_Full_xpath).click()
```

But every time it shows No such element exception!
[selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:]
I've tried with other selectors and xpaths; but none of them worked! Is there any permanent solution? Because once I was able to click on the buttons with this xpath. I had to change xpath multiple times.
Like_button_xpath    :  '//*[@id="top-level-buttons"]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf0OI.png)/a'

Dislike_button_xpath : '//*[@id="top-level-buttons"]/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[2]/a'

Comment: Using a full xpath is a really unstable way to identify an element. If you can share the full HTML of the page, I/we can likely help you write a unique a reliable selector to identify the elements you want.

Comment: can you share some HTML or a screenshot?

Comment: I've added a screenshot !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and opinion! This CSS selector is not unique and not working! You can see the full HTML yourself. Just open youtube on your browser and click on a video! Then inspect the like button.

Comment: Maybe Google block button  Like in chromedriver. I had try a lot of way but not working any more

Comment: It is still possible. I have done it

Answer (score 2):

I found Solution. Try xPath

Like_button_Full_xpath = "//div[3]/div/ytd-menu-renderer/div/ytd-toggle-button-renderer/a/yt-icon-button/button/yt-icon"

Tell me if it work.

Comment: Worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using xpath, I would use a css selector. I can't guarantee that this selector will be unique without seeing the full HTML, but I would try finding the "Like" button like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('yt-icon.style-scope.ytd-toggle-button-renderer')
```

Comment: But one more thing I've to tell you! I have tried with all the other selectors and Xpaths. but in this case, none of them worked. I guess YouTube is blocking webdriver to find out the like, dislike, and subscribe element. Because every time it is showing the No such element exception. but other elements workings fine. Is it possible? if possible then what I can do in your opinion? is there any alternative to selenium?